# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de crear conexion con Base de Datos? Java y MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda ¿influye el estilo de conexion a la base de datos en nuestro sistema? o ¿Cuál es la mejor forma para conectar a la base de datos?

Como ejemplo dejaré un modo que conozco. Lo he usado pero no conozco si existe otra forma o cuál es la mejor.

Ejemplo: Usar un método conectar dentro de la clase de conexion y otro método que seria el `getConnection()` y lleva todos los datos de la BD

> Conexión 1

```
private Connection conexion;

public static void main(String[] args) {
ConexionSql conexion = new ConexionSql();
conexion.Conectar();
}

 public ConexionSql Conectar()
{
    try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String BaseDeDatos = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVIDOR\\ESQUEMADB:PUERTO";
    conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(BaseDeDatos,"NOMBREDB","CONTRA");
        if(conexion!=null)
        {
        System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
        }
        else{System.out.println("Conexion fallida");}
        }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
    }

    return this;
}


public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception
{
    // Establece el nombre del driver a utilizar
    String dbDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";       
    // Establece la conexion a utilizar contra la base de datos
    String dbConnString = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVIDOR\\ESQUEMADB:PUERTO;dataBaseName=NOMBREDB";       
    // Establece el usuario de la base de datos
    String dbUser = "USUARIO";       
    // Establece la contraseña de la base de datos
    String dbPassword = "CONTRA";       
    // Establece el driver de conexión
    Class.forName(dbDriver).newInstance();       
    // Retorna la conexión
    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnString, dbUser, dbPassword);
}
```

Comment: La pregunta luce amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: Mejor ¿en qué sentido? Ya te digo que tener la contraseña planchada en el código no es ni óptimo, ni mantenible, ni seguro ¿puedes ser un poco más concreto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes darle una mirada al **patron singleton**  y  basado en ello implementar la conexion a la base de datos de un manera que al ser un recurso "costoso" se pueda estar reutilizando la misma conexion en diferentes partes de tu aplicacion, ojo esto solo lo recomendaria para bases de datos no multiusario ya que si buscas algo mas complejo dale una revisada a los pool de conexiones, una posible implementacion seria agroal https://agroal.github.io/ pero si encambio estas buscando algo mas simple para iniciar el patron singleton podria ser una buena idea.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.secondstack.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author Deny Prasetyo
 */
public class DatabaseConnection {

    private static DatabaseConnection instance;
    private Connection connection;
    private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jdbc";
    private String username = "root";
    private String password = "localhost";

    private DatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Database Connection Creation Failed : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static DatabaseConnection getInstance() throws SQLException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        } else if (instance.getConnection().isClosed()) {
            instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Uso de la clase

```
class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String args[]){


        Connection myConnection = DatabaseConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        //Here your code
    }
}
```

Este codigo fue extraido de github, los creditos son de  [jasoet](https://gist.github.com/jasoet/3843797)

Espero te sea util esta rustica explicacion :).

Answer (score 1):

1) El uso de `class.forName()` no es necesario a partir de jdbc 4.0. Los drivers posteriores a esta versión son cargados automaticamente por estar presentes en el classpath, lo que permite obtener una conexión como:

`Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url-base-de-datos", "user", "password");`

url-base-de-datos podria ser por ejemplo para postgress: `"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mybasededatos"`

[JDBC 4.0 and 4.1 features](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html)

2)  En cuanto a performance, lo caro en términos de tiempo, es abrir una nueva conexión. Por este motivo lo que significativamente va a mejorar la performance es utilizar un Pool de conexiones.

En un pool de conexiones, al iniciar el programa se abre una cantidad predeterminada de conexiones y se mantienen disponibles. Cuando un programa necesita una nueva conexión se le asigna una del pool. 
Cuando el programa termina de usar la conexión en lugar de cerrarla, la devuelve al pool para ser reutilizada.

Existen varias implementaciones open source que se puede utilizar.

Este link muestra algunos productos comunmente usados y tambien muestra como hacer una implementación básica.

[A Simple Guide to Connection Pooling in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling)

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, le echare un ojo al enlace pero me gusta la idea sobre todo por la orientación que tiene el soft que estoy implementando. Agradecido con tu respuesta. PD: no sabia sobre el class.forName(), pense que era un requisito de la conexión. Nuevamente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

todo depende de lo que tu necesites, pero si te refieres a que si hay alguna forma de hacerlo más eficiente pues sí, por ejemplo, en tu código tienes

```
try{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String BaseDeDatos = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVIDOR\\ESQUEMADB:PUERTO";
conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(BaseDeDatos,"NOMBREDB","CONTRA");
    if(conexion!=null)
    {
    System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
    }
    else{System.out.println("Conexion fallida");}
    }
} catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
{
}
```

Podrías mejorarlo quitando las cláusulas if/else ya que el try/catch ya te está validando CUALQUIER error que ocurra en el bloque de código y pones los mensajes de error en el catch y confirmación en el try, quedaría así:

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String BaseDeDatos = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVIDOR\\ESQUEMADB:PUERTO";
    conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(BaseDeDatos,"NOMBREDB","CONTRA");
    System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println("Conexion fallida");
}
```

También noté que escribiste el método getConnection debajo aunque ya lo habías puesto antes. No sé si el método lo hiciste tu desde cero o es un método de una librería, que de serlo, no es necesario que escribas el comportamiento del método luego.

Comment: Gracias excelente mu ayudo mucho para poder mejorarla eficiencia y obvio ahorrarme unas cuantas lineas de codigo. Muchas gracias